# What is the correct solution for that query

Tags: sql

```
insert into Orders values ('1111',
    (Select CustomerID from Customers where CustomerID = (Select CustomerID from customers where CompanyName= 'erp')),
    (Select EmployeeID from Employees where EmployeeID = (Select EmployeeID from Employees where FirstName  = 'Hello')),
    (Select ShipperID  from Shippers  Where ShipperID  = (Select ShipperID  from Shippers  where CompanyName= 'Ntat')),
    '2014-12-01','2013-12-01','22','22','aa','aa','dd','gs','ga','ga','qq');
```

i am unable to run this Query as i m getting error :

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Kindly help

Comment: why tag `facebook`? Also, please post your table schema. Last, the error is quite obvious; please review the conditions in your subquery

Comment: What is this statement suppose to do? Please share the tables structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

The `INSERT` command comes in two flavors:

**(1)** either you have all your values available, as literals or SQL Server variables - in that case, you can use the `INSERT .. VALUES()` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
VALUES(Value1, Value2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., ValueN)
```

Note: I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the list of column to insert data into - that way, you won't have any nasty surprises if suddenly your table has an extra column, or if your tables has an `IDENTITY` or computed column. Yes - it's a tiny bit more work - **once** - but then you have your `INSERT` statement as solid as it can be and you won't have to constantly fiddle around with it if your table changes.

**(2)** if you **don't** have all your values as literals and/or variables, but instead you want to rely on another table, multiple tables, or views, to provide the values, then you can use the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
   SELECT
       SourceColumn1, SourceColumn2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., SourceColumnN
   FROM
       dbo.YourProvidingTableOrView
```

Here, you must define exactly as many items in the `SELECT` as your `INSERT` expects - and those can be columns from the table(s) (or view(s)), or those can be literals or variables. Again: explicitly provide the list of columns to insert into - see above.

You can use **one or the other** - but you **cannot** mix the two - you cannot use `VALUES(...)` and then have a `SELECT` query in the middle of your list of values - pick one of the two - stick with it.

For more details and further in-depth coverage, [see the official MSDN SQL Server Books Online documentation on `INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) - a great resource for **all** questions related to SQL Server!

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

There is a design integrity issue with your application, from which you will not be able to recover at a Sql Query level.

**In Detail**

Using non-key values to lookup foreign keys during an insert is not a great idea, as you've now found - the error message indicates that one or more of the subqueries has matched multiple rows, and now you are faced with an idempotence issue.

e.g. Lets just say that in this instance, you have more than one Employee with the name 'Hello'. Your options appear to be:

- Either attribute the order to the FIRST employee with the name 'Hello' - obviously this is potentially unfair to the real employee who made the sale
- Insert multiple orders, one for each employee - but now we risk double shipping and billing issues.

So the real solution is to ensure that you carry all of the key fields (either a Primary or Unique Key, whether natural or surrogate) for each of the FK role columns through your application at all times.

This then means that you can insert the data with confidence

```
insert into Orders values ('1111',
@CustomerId, 
@EmployeeId, 
@ShipperId, 
'2014-12-01','2013-12-01','22','22','aa','aa','dd','gs','ga','ga','qq');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do this thing with the help of procedure because you are getting more than one value in select statement....

You will have to pass value one by one in insert statement

```
 create procedure test
 as
  declare @customerid int    
  declare @empid int    
  declare @shipperid int    
begin    
  set @customerid= (Select CustomerID from customers where CompanyName='erp')   
  set @empid=(Select EmployeeID from Employees where FirstName = 'Hello')    
  set @shipperid =(Select ShipperID from Shippers where CompanyName='Ntat')   
  -- but note down that it will assign last value to variable     
   -- but if it returns more than one value you will have to create a temporary table       and    --then assign value to it and will have to apply loop    
  -- like this create #temp1 (customerid id) 
  insert into orders values(@customerid,@smpid,@shipperid,'val1','val2'...ans so one)
 end
```